# Dart Returning a List of Values Sorted by Keys from a Map

Tags: list, sorting, dictionary, dart, type-conversion

I have a `Map<int, String>`, where I wish to return a list of the string values, but sorted in ascending/descending order of the int keys. This would be easy if I was returning the same iterables I also wish to sort through, such as returning list of `map.keys` or `map.values`, but I can't think of a way to do this, other than manually creating a list after iterating through the entire map with a `foreach()` and inserting values to index from map key, such as below, and then nesting another `foreach()` on that list to get rid of any null values.

```
Map<int, String> charMap = {2:'b', 1:'a', 4:'d'};
List<String> tempList = [];
List<String> charList = [];
charMap.forEach((key, value) => tempList.insert(key, value));
//tempList == ['a', 'b', '', 'd'];
charList = tempList..where((e) => e != null);
//charList == ['a', 'b', 'd'];
```

Please tell me there's a better, more efficient way? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of sorted keys (`keysAsc` or `keysDesc`) and then iterate through this list to get values from map...

```
Map<int, String> charMap = {2: 'b', 1: 'a', 4: 'd'};
List<String> charList = [];

final keysAsc = charMap.keys.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
final keysDesc = charMap.keys.toList()..sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));

for (final key in keysAsc) {
  charList.add(charMap[key]);
}

print(charList);
```